# com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER

Tags: php, android

I want to track the install referrer.

User will click the below promotional link from mobile --

```
market://details?id=com.s2s.doupnow&clickid=sdKrF5
```

The clickid is getting generated automatically, here i am showing a sample clickid.

This link is taking the user to playstore so that the user can install the app.

In the app i used com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER so that i can read the clickid when the app is installed and opened. To implement this i am using the below code, which will read the clickid and store it in the database --

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String result2 = null;
    private UserLoginTask2 mAuthTask2 = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("clickid");

        Log.d("ClickID",referrer);
        mAuthTask2 = new UserLoginTask2(referrer);
        mAuthTask2.execute((Void) null);
    }
}
```

In manifest file added the below code --

```
<receiver
            android:name=".InstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But after installing the app from playstore using the above link, i am not getting the value of clickid in the database.

Can anybody guide me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Why you don't use the new way of referer receiver ?  Eventually android will deprecate the vending referrer. I suggest you to use Google Play Referrer API.

Comment: ok i am checking the "Google Play Referrer API", just 1 doubt does it read only "referral" parameter or any parameter that we add, like in my case i am not using referrer, i m using clickid